# R : nested loop on data to strcat over the dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, parallel-processing, bigdata

I have two data sets, I want to match the postIDs and then concatenate the strings. newfile contains 40,500 rows and df2 contains 226,000 rows

```
library(pracma)
for(i in 1:nrow(newfile))
{
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2))
  {
    if(newfile[i,1]==df2[j,6])
    {
      newfile[i,3]= strcat(newfile[i,3], df2[j,4], collapse = " ")
    }
  }
}
```

`newfile[i,1]` is *postid* for newfile and `df2[j,6]` is *postid* for df2 matrix.

`newfile[i,3]` is *text* for newfile and `df2[j,4]` is *text* for df2.

I wish to concatenate the two strings if post id matches. The problem is the amount of rows in df2 and newfile makes the R go unresponsive.

Looking for any suggestion on string concatenation in R. I am also open to suggestions if I need to change from matrix to some other data type. Already tried data frame and it failed.

Comment: Why not use `merge()` data.frames then use `paste()` on 2 columns?

Comment: I am not sure but I bet that there is an easier way to do that. A piece of the two data frames you use can be very useful to try code and help you.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) , also read about merge - [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)